# Regular expression for parsing a phone number

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for a phone number.

Example,

```
1234567899 should be (123)(456)(7899)
12345678 should be (123)(456)(78)
1234567 should be (123)(456)(7)
123456 should be (123)(456)
12345 should be (123)(45)
123 should be (123)
1 should be (1)
```

I tried `/([0-9]{0,3})([0-9]{0,3})([0-9]{0,4})/` and  `/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/`

But it takes only when all the 10 numbers are in the input.

I need match then replace with `(`

Comment: May I ask, why you need a regex for that?

Comment: What about international phone numbers?  Always expect the unexpected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would appear to work:

```
/(\d{1,3})(\d{1,3})?(\d{1,4})?/
```

[Live test here](https://regex101.com/r/zM2xE1/1)

Comment: how to add parenthesis?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Mule `datawaeve` and it use `lambda`

Answer (score 1):

Check this : `/^\(\d{0,3}\)(\(\d{0,3}\))?(\(\d{0,4}\))?$/`

https://regex101.com/r/qC0fS9/2

Comment: This would appear to match the brackets? OP has the raw digits, and wants to add brackets. Also, no need for `[]` around `\d`.

Comment: Yeah I updated the regex and removed `[]`, From my understanding I though he wanted to look for the brackets.. Anyway the question has an answer now..

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern

```
((^\d{1,3})|(?<=^\d{3})(\d{1,3})|(\d+$))
```

or simplified to

```
(^\d{3}|(?<=^\d{3})\d{3}|\d+$)
```

and replace with `(\1)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/281)